# How to drag and drop the element in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am able to drag and drop the element , but my problem is that dragged element visible only within particular div tag, may be because of auto scroll, how to fix it? I need auto scroll in that area.

```
<div align="center" style="overflow: auto;  height:465px; width: 100%;" class="">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;text-align: center" draggable="true" value="" class=""
        draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag" *ngFor="let item of List ">
        <li>{{tem}}</li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: can you please create a demo project on (https://stackblitz.com/) that simulate your problem so that we can debug.